# How do I get the gdk window for a gtk window in C?

Tags: c, gtk, gdk, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to set the cursor to a watch. The problem is that gdk_set_cursor() requires a gdk_window.

How do I get the gdk_window of a gtk_window in C? I've seen examples for gtkmm and pygtk but I can't find the corresponding C function.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
GdkWindow *gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(gtk_window));
```

or, pre GTK 2.14, but now disallowed:

```
GdkWindow *gdk_window = gtk_window->window;
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem of how to get the gdkwindow. Unfortunately the mouse pointer still stays the same. 
 GdkWindow *gdkWindow = gtk_widget_get_window(window); 
 GdkCursor *gdkCursor = gdk_cursor_new(GDK_WATCH);
 gdk_window_set_cursor(gdkWindow,gdkCursor);

Comment: while(gtk_events_pending ()) { gtk_main_iteration (); } often helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case gdk_window_set_cursor did not work because gtk_widget_get_window was returning an invalid handle because it was not already realized. Moving those lines after the window is made visible solved it for me.

From docs:

... For example, widget->window will be created when a widget is realized. Normally realization happens implicitly; if you show a widget and all its parent containers, then the widget will be realized and ...