# How to receive characters from input method in gtk+2?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk2, fcitx

I'm creating a application using C & gtk+2 with custom text input, pango to draw the characters to `GtkDrawingArea`, everything works fine until a user tells me that he can't input Chinese characters in my application, he use a fcitx input method.

Currently I'm using simple `key_press_event` & `key_release_event` GSignals to implement character input, but I don't think it will work for input methods, I found a [GtkIMContext](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkIMContext.html) api but not sure how to use it.

So, my question is, how to receive characters from fcitx/ibus input methods in gtk+2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the way myself.

First of all, I have a `GtkWindow *`.

```
GtkWidget *window;
```

To support input methods, I have to initialize a `GtkIMContext` and set the client window, `gtk_im_context_set_client_window` use `GdkWindow *` as its second parameter.

```
GtkIMContext *im_context = gtk_im_multicontext_new();
GdkWindow *gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(window));
gtk_im_context_set_client_window(im_context, gdk_window);
```

The last step, set focus to this `im_context`.

```
gtk_im_context_focus_in(im_context);
```

Now the input methods are available! After this, you can listen for signals of `GtkIMContext` to handle inputs.

```
g_signal_connect(im_context, "commit",
      G_CALLBACK(commit_callback), NULL);
g_signal_connect(im_context, "preedit-changed",
      G_CALLBACK(preedit_changed_callback), NULL);
g_signal_connect(im_context, "retrieve-surrounding",
      G_CALLBACK(retrieve_surrounding_callback), NULL);
g_signal_connect(im_context, "delete-surrounding",
      G_CALLBACK(delete_surrounding_callback), NULL);
```

In order to receive english characters in `commit` signal's callback, you must listen for `key-press-event` signal and use `gtk_im_context_filter_keypress` function.

```
static gboolean key_callback(GtkWidget *widget,
                             GdkEventKey *event,
                             GtkIMContext *im_context) {
  return gtk_im_context_filter_keypress(im_context, event);
}

g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event",
      G_CALLBACK(key_callback), im_context);
```

Refenerces:

1. https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gtk/gtkentry.h
2. https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gtk/gtkentry.c
3. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkIMContext.html
4. [How do I get the gdk window for a gtk window in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264625/how-do-i-get-the-gdk-window-for-a-gtk-window-in-c)