# Use functionality of GdkWindow for GtkWindow

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gdk

I have a GtkWindow and want to use the functionality of [gdk_window_get_visible_region()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-visible-region) and [gdk_window_shape_combine_region_()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-shape-combine-region) on them in order to create a custom shaped window.
I understand that GtkWindow and GdkWindow are very different objects.

I can't find a way to connect the two. I already have my GtkWindow with a partly opaque cairo drawing on it. Is there a way to simply convert it to a GdkWindow?

Comment: You can use `gtk_widget_get_window(GtkWidget *)` to get the GdkWindow for your GtkWindow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the gdk window for a gtk window in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264625/how-do-i-get-the-gdk-window-for-a-gtk-window-in-c)